# Generator GFCI Outlet Tripping

Tags: electrical, gfci, generator, audio

Recently I purchased this 4375 watt generator from HF:

https://www.harborfreight.com/merchandising-promotions/brands/predator/predator-generators/4375-watt-gas-powered-portable-generator-epa-iii-63962.html-

I have heard some bad things about HF's generators but the insanely low price is what attracted me - however, before I go about returning or upgrading I want to eliminate any issues in my wiring setup.

Here's the setup: Generator has two 120vac GFCI outlets each of which I am running a 100 foot 16 gauge extension cord out of. Plugged into each of these extension cords are two 3-outlet wall taps, and plugged into these wall taps are different surge protectors, powering audio gear such as two audio interfaces (65w) laptop (100w or so) guitar amps (50w or less) an LED lamp (150w) and so on. Nothing is daisy chained, the audio interfaces and laptop are on one outlet and the amps are on another so the loops are separated.

Here's the trouble: When plugging in specifically the laptop, the GFCI for that outlet tripped immediately, without even turning the laptop on. After this point, just plugging in the audio interface was enough to trip it. Later, just turning on the surge protector was enough to trip it. Tried the other outlet, different surge protector, just the laptop - same issue. Now weirdly, I was able to run two guitar amps and pedalboards off of one extension cord with no trouble - maybe about 300-400 watts altogether.

I have considered going for higher gauge extension cords? Or even biting the bullet and getting a Honda inverter generator. Any ideas you guys might have? Thanks so much.

p.s. yes, the generator is grounded, to a galvanized steel rod about a foot deep.

Comment: Are these 2-wire or 3-wire cords?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica You mean are they grounded? Yes, all cords and surge protectors in the system are grounded (have ground wire).

Comment: Does the laptop's adapter have a two-prong or a three-prong power cord?

Comment: I meant the plugs on the particular appliances that are tripping the GFCI.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yes, three-prong with a transformer before the laptop plug

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica sorry, yes they are all three-prong.

Comment: Have you ever plugged those appliances into a regular GFCI that's built into a house that's powered by AC utility power?  What happens then?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Thanks Harper, I just tested all of those devices that were tripping the generator GFCI in a bathroom GFCI outlet and the outlet did not trip

Comment: Try connecting directly to the generator without the 100’ cord or surge protector.